# Use config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict only for specific controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mass-assignment

I would like to raise exceptions when trying to mass-assign an invalid attribute in the production environment, but only for a specific controller.

I figured I should add `config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict` to `production.rb`, but that would raise exceptions app-wide.

Is there a way to only use the strict mode for a specific Controller?

The reason is that in normal usage I don't want the user to be server 500-errors, but there is a critical (data import) section in which I would like to rescue from the mass-assignment error and provide information to the user.

I'm running on Rails 3.2

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to have some [exception handling mechanism](http://spraints.github.com/blog/2012/06/25/rails-3-exception-handling/). You can catch the exception in application_controller and do your checking there.